# How can I spy on the `[]=` method in Ruby hash?

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash. One of these keys is `daily_budget`. After some process, `daily_budget` has been changed while all other keys' values have not. Either the hash's value for that key changed, or I'm cloning the hash and setting that value on the cloned hash.

I want to spy on the `Hash#[]=` method to figure out where this happens. I'd monkey patch it, watch for a key named `daily_budget`, and dump a stack trace whenever it is set.

I was trying to use a code like this:

```
module HashPatches
  def []=(key, value)
    puts ">>>> hey! I got here!"
    super(key, value)
  end
end

Hash.send(:include, HashPatches)
```

It seems like this change is ignored, while other patches on `Hash` are working. Did I do something wrong?

I also tried using `set_trace_func` to trace calls to the hash with this code,

```
set_trace_func proc { |event, file, line, id, binding, classname|
  if file =~ /\/my_project_name\//
    puts ">>>> #{id}"
    puts ">>>> #{classname}"
    puts ">>>> #{event}"
    puts ">>>> #{file}"
    puts ">>>> #{line}"
  end
}
```

but `:[]=` isn't traced. I'd removed the monkey patch. I couldn't get usages of `:[]=` to appear in this output.

Is there any way to spy changes to hashes so I can track down where this key's value is changed?

Comment: Probably would be better to wrap the offending Hash in a proxy class and track all the calls than it would be to monkey patch the Hash class. Also remember key reassignment need not occur for the value to change e.g. `h = {n: "hello"}; h[:n].concat(" world"); h[:n] #=> "hello world"` or `h = {n: 12}; h[:n] += 12; h[:n] #=> 24` and furthermore `Hash#[]=` is not the only method that modifies key => value assignments other methods can do that such as `store`, `transform_values`, `update`,`merge`, etc.

Comment: I agree with you, but I'm not sure if there's another instance of hash being created by `dup`ing this hash or not. It's just one way to see what's going on.

Comment: If you wrap it in a proxy object you can track all the calls made including duplication and wrap the duplication in another proxy object that is why I suggested it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Hash.send(:include, HashPatches)` only makes your `HashPatches#[]=` to be called when (the original) `Hash#[]=` is not available, which is not the case. Also, `super` in your `HashPatches#[]=` definition will not work since the superclass `Object` of your `HashPatches` does not have `[]=`.

To give precedence to your `HashPatches#[]=` over the original `Hash#[]=`, you need to do:

```
Hash.prepend(HashPatches)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can to monkey patch the `Hash` class itself.  Put this inside the module / class definition,

```
class Hash
  def []=(arg)
    # do your magic here with a debugger or pry
  end 
end
```

Edit: This way is obsolete, but leaving for reference.

Comment: That was the old way, indeed. It's been obsolete for 5 years now. Modern way is `Module#prepend`